# Add a css class or id name to Html.ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I would like to wither add an additional CSS class or give an ID to my `@Html.ValidationSummary()` tag. I tried the `new` keyword like I would with other HTML Helpers but gives an anonymous type to string conversion error. Is this possible to do and if so how?

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, new { @id = "validationSummary" })
```

Comment: The default `.validation-summary-errors` class not enough?

Comment: @RosdiKasim That would be a global change, there are certain pages in my app that have a different look/feel to them then others so I need to change it to match those.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no method overload for Html.ValidationSummary that receives (Boolean, Object). There is one that receives (Boolean, String, Object) though.

You could try this:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @id = "validationSummary" })
```

Comment: That gives conversion errors for each one. First is string to Bool, second is bool to string, then Anonymous type to string.

Comment: I mistook the order of the parameters, updated the answer, please try again and let me know.